# Convex quadrangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

there is a quadrangles ABCD with $|AB| + |BC| = |AD| + |DC|$. The beam $AB$ cuts the beam $DC$ in the point $X$. The beam $AD$ cuts the beam $BC$ in the point $Y$.

Now show that

\begin{equation*}
|AX| + |XC| = |AY| + |YC|.
\end{equation*}

Hope you can help me. I just realize that there are some circles that may be useful to show some equalities.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that $|CD|=|DC|$, so the top inequality is actually $|AB| = |AD|$.

Comment: I corrected it, it has to be $|BC|$ instead of $|CD|$ ;).

Comment: Some thoughts: your expression $|AB| + |BC| = |AD| + |DC|$ suggests that $B$ and $D$ are points on an ellipse with $A$ and $C$ as foci. $B$ and $D$ probably need to be on different sides of $AC$ for $ABCD$ to be a simple quadrilateral.  You may be trying to show that $X$ and $Y$ lie on another ellipse with $A$ and $C$ as foci.

Comment: @Henry Hmm thanks for hint, but I just know that a point P(x, y) will be on an ellipse if $\frac{(x - h_{1})^2}{r_{x}^2} + \frac{(y - h_{2})}{r_{y}^2} = 1$ with $h_{1}$ and $h_{2}$ are the coordinates of the center-point and $r_{x}$ and $r_{y}$ are the semi-achses.

Answer (score 2):

This theorem is known as [Urquhart's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UrquhartsTheorem.html) (or at least half of it). There is an elementary synthetic solution, which you can find at [Cut The Knot](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/UrquhartElementary.shtml).

Comment: thanks for this hint ;) Your my lifesaver ;).

Comment: @grok This isn't really a hint, it's just a link to complete solution.